# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at push (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, prototype, push

Why this would throw an error,

```js
const callback = Array.prototype.push;
callback(1)
```

But this would not,

```js
Array.prototype.push(1)
```

I kind of know that the reason is that `this` context is lost in the first case, but can you give me more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this`, inside a function, depends (in most cases) on how the function is invoked. callback() is invoked without any object. In that case this will point to the global object window(if you are in browser). You cannot do window.push().

Extra : One exception to the most cases statement is arrow functions.